# OpenID using Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, openid

I am in the process of creating a website and I want users to be able to login with an openID account. I am using java and the play framework. They will need to be able to login to see certain parts of the website.

I have read the information here: 
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaOpenID

And I have downloaded openid4java here:
http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/downloads/detail?name=openid4java-0.9.6.662.tar.gz&can=2&q=

Should I just import all of the .jars from this download as reference libraries in my project?

I am not really too sure where to begin with configuring this as the documentation on plays website seems vague.

Any tips provided are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need only OpenId authentication, or whole authentication/authorization stack?

Comment: My original plan was just to support OpenID and the logins it supports (facebook, gmail etc) and if a user didn't have one these accounts they could simply create an openID account. Although I am looking at the Play! Authenticate module you have linked and it seems attractive. My only concern is how difficult it is to implement as I am very new to play!. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Actually you just need to copy existing code from the Java sample and merge it with your own: https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/tree/master/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage with good IDE it should be quite easy job, there is a description for implementing this: https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/blob/master/samples/java/Getting%20Started.md

Comment: This is great. Thank you very much for your helpful response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is full  authentication/authorization stack available as a module - [Play! Authenticate](http://joscha.github.com/play-authenticate/)

It allows you to register users with many providers, also with OpenID or just an email. Additionally there's support for multilanguage, template customization (also in emails) etc. Finally it's shipped originally with [DeadBolt2](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2/blob/master/README.textile) - authorization solution with roles and users permissions.

Answer (score 3):

Much easier is to use the http://securesocial.ws/ plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Like any other dependency, you should add the OpenID dependencies to your project as part of the [sbt dependency management](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/SBTDependencies) so that they will be available in runtime.